# Efficient scalar update to matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $N$ be the number of data points. Let $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_X$ be fixed covariance matrices. I have an online algorithm for discrete time that computes

$$
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_N = (\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0 ^{-1} + N \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_X^{-1})^{-1}
$$

at each time step. Thus, $N$ increases by $1$ at the rate of the data stream. I would prefer to not compute a matrix inversion at each time step, since the dimension of the $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$'s may be large. Is it possible to do an efficient update without using a matrix inversion?

$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_N &= (\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0 ^{-1} + N \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_X^{-1})^{-1}
\\
&\Downarrow
\\
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{N+1} &= (\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0 ^{-1} + (N+1) \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_X^{-1})^{-1}.
\end{aligned}
$$

It is easy to imagine fast updates to the precision matrices,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_N &= \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0 ^{-1} + N \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_X^{-1}
\\
&\Downarrow
\\
\boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{N+1} &= \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_N - N \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_X^{-1} + (N+1) \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_X^{-1}.
\end{aligned}
$$

But I'm stuck inverting this if I need $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{N+1}$.